# Is there a way to match Regex based on previous capture group, not captured previously?

Tags: regex

Okay, so the task is that there is a string that can either look like `post`, or `post put` or even `get put post`. All of these must be matched. Preferably deviances like `[space]post`, or `get[space]` should not be matched.

Currently I came up with this

```
^(post|put|delete|get)(( )(post|put|delete|get))*$
```

However I'm not satisfied with it, because I had to specify `(post|put|delete|get)` twice. It also matches duplications like `post post`.

I'd like to somehow use a backreference(?) to the first group so that I don't have to specify the same condition twice.

However, backreference `\1` would help me **only** match `post post`, for example, and that's the opposite of what I want. I'd like to match a word in the first capture group that was **NOT** previously found in the string.

Is this even possible? I've been looking through SO questions, but my Google-fu is eluding me.

Comment: Tried [`^(post|put|delete|get)( (?!\1)(?1))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/aR0tA4/1)? It will work with PCRE. What is your regex flavor? It is crucial to know what language/regex library you are using in this case.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ...I missed out on `(?1)` - I didn't even know it existed, but apparently that's the key to this solution apart from the negative lookahead. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Note for the accepted answer: true, flavors really do matter in regex engines, so for Javascript, one needs to replace the recursive subroutine call with [the first call and some minor adjustments](https://regex101.com/r/xV9eA1/1#javascript): `^((post|put|delete|get)(?!.*\2))( (post|put|delete|get)(?!.*\4))*$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a PCRE-based regex engine, you may use [subroutine calls](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) like `(?n)` to recurse the subpatterns.

```
^(post|put|delete|get)( (?!\1)(?1))*$
                              ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aR0tA4/1)

**Expression details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(post|put|delete|get)` - Group 1 matching one of the alternatives as literal substrings
- `( (?!\1)(?1))*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - - a space
  - `(?!\1)` - a [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if the text after the current location is identical to the one captured into Group 1 due to [**backreference**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1`
  - `(?1)` - a [**subroutine call**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) to the first capture group (i.e. it uses the same pattern used in Group 1)
- `$` - end of string

## UPDATE

In order to avoid matching strings like `get post post`, you need to also add a negative lookahead *into* Group 1 so that the subroutine call was aware that we do not want to match the same value that was captured into Group 1.

```
^((post|put|delete|get)(?!.*\2))( (?1))*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aR0tA4/2)

The difference is that we capture the alternations into **Group 2** and add the negative lookahead `(?!.*\2)` to disallow any occurrences of the word we captured further in the string. The `( (?1))*` remains intact: now, the subroutine recurses the whole Capture Group 1 subpattern with the lookahead.

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you. I didn't know about subroutine calls in regex.

Comment: Note that it is not available in many regex flavors. In Ruby, you can use `\g<N>` instead of `(?N)`, but in .NET, there is no way to do the same.

Comment: Wait a second, it seems to have a minor issue. Apparently it doesn't match `post post`, but it *does* match `get post post` (which it shouldn't). Is there a way to somehow make it not match the second appearance of `post` in the second case? Apparently it still matches if the repeating word is "not the same as the very first match for the control group", so `get post get` does not match, but `get post put post` does.

Comment: Use `^((post|put|delete|get)(?!.*\2))( (?1))*$`

Comment: This last one works, although I'll have to look at it a bit more because `(?!.*\2)` is a bit cryptic and comprehend it. This is amazing, thank you!